# MFC data storage guidance

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm writing an application which will fetch all the network adapter card info and display that on screen. For my purpose I need to store them for future use.

Currently I'm using an array of `CStringArray` to store the data but the size of the array is fixed.

```
//member of class
CStringArray m_arrAdapterData[10];

//enumeration of network card
int iAdapterCount = 0;
while(some loop condition)
{
    CString cstr = _T("Some data");
    m_arrAdapterData[iAdapterCount].Add(cstr);
    cstr = _T("Some data");
    m_arrAdapterData[iAdapterCount].Add(cstr);
    iAdapterCount++;
}
```

Now, I'm thinking to use double dimension vector or similar. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried CStringList?

Comment: MFC have more [collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/942860sh.aspx) than `CStringArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [vector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxcsf7y7.aspx) ?

It allows fast random access to any element and can handle dynamic allocation.

You can modify your code somewhat as below to work with vectors.

```
#include <vector>
.
.
.
//member of class

  vector<CString> m_arrAdapterData;
vector<vector<CString>> infoVectors;

//populating
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j< 5 ; j++)
   {
      CString cstr = _T("Some data");
      m_arrAdapterData.push_back(cstr);
   }
   infoVectors.push_back(m_arrAdapterData);
}

//retrieving
vector<vector<CString>>::iterator outerItr = infoVectors.begin();
while(outerItr != infoVectors.end())
{
   vector<CString>::iterator innerItr = outerItr->begin();
   while(innerItr != outerItr->end())
   {
     cout<<*innerItr;
     innerItr++;
   }
   outerItr++;
}
```

Comment: I need to use multidimensional vector as m_arrAdapterData will hold the info for all the adapters, and the info wont be a single CString, one adapter will have multiple infos i.e. multiple CString.

Comment: You can use vector of vector ie `vector<vector<CString>> multiVector`

Comment: Yes, but cannot figure out the code. Could you please show some snippet.